# Excel file doesn't generated using tkinter pandas library?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, user-interface, tkinter

I am working with **ESP32** and **AHT25** sensor to measure temperature and humidity.
I created a GUI using ***Tkinter*** library that displays the Temperature and Humidity values on the GUI. And also that temp & Humi values stored in ***excel*** file continuously. That created by using ***pandas*** library. This is my full code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import requests
from tkinter import messagebox
from idlelib.tooltip import Hovertip
import re
import pandas as pd
import time

class DeviceButton(tk.Button):
  def __init__(self, master, id, ip, excel_file = 
                 "th.data.xlsx"):
    super().__init__(master, font="Times 15", 
                     bg="SkyBlue1", fg="black",
                     highlightthickness=2, 
                     command=self.show_details)
    self.button_counter = 0
    self.id = id
    self.ip = ip
    self.excel_file = excel_file
    self.get_ip_data()

    self.excel_file = excel_file

    self.df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Temperature 
                        (Celsius)", "Humidity (%)"])

  def get_ip_data(self):
    print(f"The id number is {self.id}")
    print(f"The ip address is {self.ip}")
    print(type(self.ip))

    response = requests.get(f"http://{self.ip}/")
    data = response.json()
    print(data)

    temp = round(data['temperature'], 2)
    humi = round(data['humidity'], 2)
    id_json = data['id']
    print(f"temperature for id {self.id} is {temp}")
    print(f"humidity for id {self.id} is {humi}")

    if int(id_json) == int(self.id):
        self.config(text=f"Device {self.id}\nTemperature: {temp}°C\nHumidity: {humi}%")
        self.after(2000, self.get_ip_data)
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Error!", f"Invalid ID")

    return temp, humi

  def store_data_in_dataframe(self, temp, humi):

    new_data = {
        "Temperature (Celsius)": temp,
        "Humidity (%)": humi
    }
    self.df = self.df._append(new_data, ignore_index=True)

  def store_data_in_excel(self):
    self.df.to_excel(self.excel_file, index=False)

  def run(self):
    while True:
        temp, humi = self.get_ip_data()
        self.store_data_in_dataframe(temp, humi)
        self.store_data_in_excel()
        time.sleep(5)
  def show_details(self):
    self.new_window = tk.Toplevel()
    self.new_window.geometry("500x500")
    self.new_window.config(bg="LightSkyBlue1")
    self.new_window.resizable(0, 0)

    self.label = tk.Label(self.new_window,
                          text=self["text"],
                          bg="LightSkyBlue1",
                          fg="black",
                          font="Times 20 bold")
    self.label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.label.after(2000, self.repeat)
    print(self["text"])

  def repeat(self):
    self.label.configure(text=self["text"])


class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.button_counter = 0
    self.button_position = [(100, 100), (300, 100), (500, 100), (700, 100), (900, 100), (1100, 100), (1300, 100),
                            (100, 200), (300, 200), (500, 200), (700, 200), (900, 200), (1100, 200), (1300, 200),
                            (100, 300), (300, 300), (500, 300), (700, 300), (900, 300), (1100, 300), (1300, 300),
                            (100, 400), (300, 400), (500, 400), (700, 400), (900, 400), (1100, 400), (1300, 400),
                            (100, 500), (300, 500), (500, 500), (700, 500), (900, 500), (1100, 500), (1300, 500),
                            (100, 600), (300, 600), (500, 600), (700, 600), (900, 600), (1100, 600), (1300, 600)]

    self.frame = tk.Frame(self, height=50, width=500)
    self.frame.pack()

    logo_image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\Kuralmozhi.R\\Downloads\\icons8-temperature-65.png')
    test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo_image)
    self.logo = tk.Label(self.frame, image=test)
    self.logo.image = test
    self.logo.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    self.title_label = tk.Label(self.frame,
                                text="ESP32 
                 Temperature & Humidity Measurement",
                                fg="DodgerBlue2",
                                font='Times 25 bold')
    self.title_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    self.status_frame = tk.Frame(self,
                                 bd=1,
                                 bg="DodgerBlue2",
                                 relief=tk.SUNKEN)
    self.status_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

    self.button1 = tk.Button(self.status_frame,
                             text="+",
                             bg="DodgerBlue2",
                             fg="white",
                             font='Helvetica 25 bold',
                             relief=tk.FLAT,
                             cursor="hand2",
                             command=self.add_device)
    self.button1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=5)

    self.add_device_label = tk.Label(self.status_frame,
                                     text="Add New Device",
                                     bg="DodgerBlue2",
                                     fg="white",
                                     font='Times 20 bold')
    self.add_device_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=5)

    myTip = Hovertip(self.button1, "Add new Device")

  def add_device(self):
    self.window = tk.Toplevel()
    self.window.title("Add new device")
    self.window.resizable(0, 0)
    self.window.config(bg="white")

    main_x = self.winfo_rootx()
    main_y = self.winfo_rooty()
    main_width = self.winfo_width()
    main_height = self.winfo_height()

    second_width = 700
    second_height = 400

    x = main_x + main_width / 2 - second_width / 2
    y = main_y + main_height / 2 - second_height / 2

    self.window.geometry(f"{second_width}x{second_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")

    self.id_label = tk.Label(self.window,
                             text="Enter ID Number: ",
                             font='Helvetica 12 bold',
                             bg="white",
                             fg="navy")
    self.id_label.place(x=200, y=100)

    self.id_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, fg="DodgerBlue2", font="Times 15 italic", bd=0)
    self.id_entry.insert(0, "ID Number......")
    self.id_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda args: self.id_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
    self.id_entry.place(x=350, y=100)

    self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.window, width=200, height=2, bg='navy').place(x=350, y=125)

    self.ip_label = tk.Label(self.window,
                             text="Enter IP Address: ",
                             font='Helvetica 12 bold',
                             bg="white",
                             fg="navy")
    self.ip_label.place(x=200, y=150)

    self.ip_entry = tk.Entry(self.window, fg="DodgerBlue2", font="Times 15 italic", bd=0)
    self.ip_entry.insert(0, "IP Address......")
    self.ip_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda args: self.ip_entry.delete('0', 'end'))
    self.ip_entry.place(x=350, y=150)

    self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self.window, width=200, height=2, bg='navy').place(x=350, y=175)

    self.add_button = tk.Button(self.window,
                                text="Add",
                                bg="DodgerBlue2",
                                fg="white",
                                font='Helvetica 12 bold',
                                cursor="hand2",
                                command=lambda: [self.check(), self.add_command()])
    self.add_button.place(x=350, y=200)

  def check(self):

    ip_address = self.ip_entry.get()

    ip_regex = r"^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$"

    if self.id_entry.get() == 'ID Address......' or self.id_entry.get() == '':
        tk.messagebox.showwarning("Warning!", "Please fill the required details")
        self.add_device()

    elif self.ip_entry.get() == 'IP Address......' or self.ip_entry.get() == '':
        tk.messagebox.showwarning("Warning!", "Please fill the required details")
        self.add_device()

    elif not re.match(ip_regex, ip_address):
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid IP address format.")
        self.add_device()

  def add_command(self):

    if self.button_counter > len(self.button_position):
        return
    x, y = self.button_position[self.button_counter]
    result_button = DeviceButton(self, self.id_entry.get(), self.ip_entry.get(), "th.data.xlsx")
    result_button.place(x=x, y=y)
    self.button_counter += 1
    self.window.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = MainApplication()
   app.state("zoomed")
   app.mainloop()
```

my GUI works fine but ***excel*** file cannot be generated. Can anyone solve this error?

Comment: What means "cannot be generated"?What exactly happens (if there is an error message show it completely as properly formatted text in the question)?

Comment: You have never called `DeviceButton.run()`, so why do you expect the Excel file to be created?

Comment: Where should I call "DeviceButton.run()" ? Can you explain in detail @acw1668?

Comment: It is your code and you determine how the code runs.

Comment: I put on result_button.run() in the end of my code. It creates excel file but my Button my result button does not created in GUI. I don't know how to do this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have never called `self.store_data_in_dataframe()` and `self.store_data_in_excel()` in your code, the Excel file will never be created.

The simple way is to call these two function inside `self.get_ip_data()`:

```py
class DeviceButton(tk.Button):
  def __init__(self, master, id, ip, excel_file =
                 "th.data.xlsx"):
    super().__init__(master, font="Times 15",
                     bg="SkyBlue1", fg="black",
                     highlightthickness=2,
                     command=self.show_details)
    self.button_counter = 0
    self.id = id
    self.ip = ip
    self.excel_file = excel_file

    self.df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Temperature (Celsius)", "Humidity (%)"])
    # should call self.get_ip_data() after creating the dataframe
    self.get_ip_data()

  def get_ip_data(self):
    print(f"The id number is {self.id}")
    print(f"The ip address is {self.ip}")
    print(type(self.ip))

    response = requests.get(f"http://{self.ip}/")
    data = response.json()
    print(data)

    temp = round(data['temperature'], 2)
    humi = round(data['humidity'], 2)
    id_json = data['id']
    print(f"temperature for id {self.id} is {temp}")
    print(f"humidity for id {self.id} is {humi}")

    if int(id_json) == int(self.id):
        self.config(text=f"Device {self.id}\nTemperature: {temp}°C\nHumidity: {humi}%")
        self.store_data_in_dataframe(temp, humi) # save data to dataframe
        self.store_data_in_excel() # save dataframe to Excel file
        self.after(2000, self.get_ip_data)
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Error!", f"Invalid ID")

    return temp, humi

    ...
```